# cin skipping in while

Tags: c++, while-loop, iostream

Why is my cin being skipped in the following while?

```
int main() {
        int option;
        cin >> option;
        while(!cin.good()) {
                cout << "Looping" << endl;
                cin >> option;
        }
}
```

Comment: You're not typing in a letter, are you?

Comment: I expected to stop to allow you to input but it just did LoopingLoopingLooping etc. I have tried this on cygwin vista and g++ ubuntu linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Errors in iostreams are sticky. You need to clear the error state before `cin` works again.

```
int main() {
        int option;
        cin >> option;
        while(!cin.good()) {
                cout << "Looping" << endl;
                cin.clear(); // ignore erroneous line of input:
                cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
                cin >> option;
        }
}
```

Comment: menu.cpp: In member function ‘int notekeeper::menu::getOption()’:
menu.cpp:27: error: invalid conversion from ‘int (*)()throw ()’ to ‘std::streamsize’
menu.cpp:27: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::ignore(std::streamsize, typename _Traits::int_type) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]’

Comment: @Will: `max` is a function; note the parentheses after it.